# How can I create a user in SQL Server Express database I added to my project?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-express

How can I create a SQL user in a SQL Server Express database that I added to my project?

I need to create a user to use in a connection string that doesn't use Integrated Security.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You would need to create a SQL Authenticated login first with [CREATE LOGIN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189751.aspx) then add a user associated with that login to your database by using [CREATE USER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173463.aspx).

```
USE [master]
GO
CREATE LOGIN [JohnEgbert] WITH PASSWORD=N'YourPassword', 
                 DEFAULT_DATABASE=[YourDB], CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=OFF
GO
USE [YourDB]
GO
CREATE USER [JohnEgbert] FOR LOGIN [JohnEgbert] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
GO
```

Answer (score 15):

If you create a SQL login and a SQL user without errors, but then get an error when trying to connect, you may have the SQL Authentication mode disabled. To check, run:

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('IsIntegratedSecurityOnly')
```

If this returns 1, then SQL Authentication (mixed mode) is disabled.
You can change this setting using SSMS, regedit, or T-SQL:

```
EXEC xp_instance_regwrite N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', N'Software\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\MSSQLServer', N'LoginMode', REG_DWORD, 2
```

Then restart the SQL Server service, and create a login and a user, here with full permissions:

```
CREATE LOGIN myusername WITH PASSWORD=N'mypassword', 
                 DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master], CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=OFF

EXEC sp_addsrvrolemember 'myusername', 'sysadmin'
CREATE USER myusername FOR LOGIN myusername WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
```

Comment: Note I had the same issue that you mention here, but solved it right clicking on my DB serve '(local)\sqlexpress'-->Properties->Security.  There is a radio button for Server Authentication with two options: 1) Windows Authentication Mode 2) SQL Server and Windows Authentication Mode.  My initial setting was 'Windows Authentication Mode' and I changed to #2 (both). After that I as able to log in with Sql Server Authentication.

Comment: Extremely helpful advice from both of you - thank you :)

Comment: That was it. Mixed mode wasn't turned on.